# Mysql error #1932 "Table doesn't exist in engine" after changing datadir in my.ini

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin, xampp

I changed the `datadir` in `my.ini` so that I can use a data folder that's on my Google Drive account: `datadir = "C:/Users/Santiago/Google Drive/mysql/data"`

After doing this and running phpmyadmin I can see every schema and tables, but  when I try to perform a `SELECT * FROM table` query I get an `error #1932 "Table doesn't exist in engine"`
 If I perform `show variables like 'datadir'` it points to the right folder

What I'm trying to achieve is to sync my htdocs folder and data folder to a Google Drive account. I have xampp 5.6.28 installed in two computers (home and work), one runs with Windows 7 and the other with Windows 10. All DBs where created in W7. 
Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 0):

You can try to put the full data folder in google drive and edit het following lines in my.ini:

```
innodb_data_home_dir = "C:/Users/<your username>/Google Drive/mysql/data"
innodb_data_file_path = ibdata1:10M:autoextend
innodb_log_group_home_dir = "C:/Users/<your username>/Google Drive/mysql/data"
innodb_log_arch_dir = "C:/Users/<your username>/Google Drive/mysql/data"
```

make sure to remove the "#" for the last line. This worked for me.

Comment: Will try this. Thanks for the answer Jop !!